# Congruence and similarity

Tags: geometry

The diagram shows two right angled triangles, $ABC$ and $BCD$, with $AD = 6~\text{cm}$ and $CD = 2~\text{cm}$.  By using similar triangles or otherwise, find the length of the side $BD$.

[image]

Congruence and similarity , I have problems trying to find the 2 similar triangles

Comment: You need to show that $\triangle ABD \sim \triangle BCD$.  What is the relationship between $\angle ABD$ and $\angle CBD$?

Answer (score 0):

In $\triangle$ $ABC$ and$\triangle$ $BDC$,

$\angle$$ABC$= $\angle$ $BDC$(each $90$) and

$\angle$$ ACB$ = $\angle$$BCD$ (common),

so both $\triangle$'s are similar by A-A criterion.